# Send message using mutt from non-default account

Tags: email, command-line, mutt, multiple-accounts

You can send a message via mutt with a command like so:

```
mutt -s "Test Email" user@example.com < message.txt
```

This will send a message from the default account.

I have two e-mail accounts set up with mutt and I want to send a message from the account that is not the default. I tried changing the From field via `-e 'my_hdr From:other@domain.com` but the attempt failed with a `SendAsDeniedException` (my default e-mail is with Microsoft outlook.com).

So how can I send a message from the other account via the command line? (I want to automate my messages.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have configured your accounts in separate files. Simply load the corresponding configuration beforehand.

```
mutt -e "source ~/.mutt/accounts/account1" -s "Test Email" user@example.com < message.txt
```

Comment: `echo "your message body" | neomutt -F <your_muttrc_for_your_email_account> -s "your message subject line" <email_target_address>`